# Why isn't ASP.NET Identity seeding the 2nd user when I update the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Never had a problem like this before... So the idea is I'm seeing an admin and a basic user into my database:

For simplicity sake I've removed most of the fields I'm adding. Suffice it to say both users have values in the same columns and therefore there should be no conflict where a column is null that should be populated.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = "ortund@fudge.com",
    UserName = "ortund"
};
userManager.Create(user, "moomin");
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, nameof(Helpers.Roles.ForumAdmin));

user = new ApplicationUser
{
   Email = "ilu@fudge.com",
   UserName = "Ilüvatar"
};
userManager.Create(user, "Ly@12157114");
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, nameof(Helpers.Roles.ForumUser));
```

So this adds the "ortund" user fine and its added the user to the `ForumAdmin` role perfectly fine but the line where that addition to the role occurs is through an `InvalidOperationException` saying *UserId not found.*

What is going on? I don't understand what user id it's looking for much less why it can't find it...

Here's the full stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<AddToRoleAsync>d__83.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.AddToRole[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, TKey userId, String role)
   at Forum.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in E:\Development\Backup\Git\fudge\Forum\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 54
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

Comment: You use `userManager.Create(user, "moomin");` followed by `userManager.AddToRole(user.Id`. `Create` returns the status of the operation. If  it failed, `user.Id` won't be an actual value

Comment: But the user is created and added to the database so it can't have failed can it? I mean unless I' missing something